# TFS 2015.4 Unable to start or detach a collection

Tags: tfs-2015

I'm having an issue with a particular team project collection on my TFS2015.4. This collection caused issues when I wanted to upgrade TFS sometime ago as well. I was able to detach it in TFS2013.3 and then upgraded. Now I want to upgrade to TFS2017 and I don't know how to resolve the issue with this collection.

```
TF400868: Job definition not found for JobId d891ac97-ddf1-42df-8242-3cd4bd607790
```

Here is the current status:

- Won't detach
- Won't start
- Status -> ApplyPatch -> won't execute
- Stays Offline
- One project inside and stays at 'Deleting' state

If I try to start, I get this error:

```
TF400783: The host 'MyDAS' cannot be started. The host is in the process of being serviced. The servicing may have failed and needs to be restarted and completed before the host can be started.
```

I did a pre-production upgrade to TFS2017 and there was a validation error with this collection's state that prevented me from finishing the upgrade.

[image: General tab]
[image: Detaching result]
[image: Status tab]
[image: ApplyPatch Rerun]
[image: Team Projects tab]

The detailed log for ApplyPatch Rerun has just one failure point:

```
[12:29:58.457] +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[12:29:58.457] Executing step: Populate commit changes
[12:29:58.457]   Executing step: 'Populate commit changes' Git.M83PopulateCommitChanges (1017 of 1201)
[12:29:58.477]   [Error] TF400868: Job definition not found for JobId d891ac97-ddf1-42df-8242-3cd4bd607790.
[12:29:58.480]   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobDefinitionNotFoundException: TF400868: Job definition not found for JobId d891ac97-ddf1-42df-8242-3cd4bd607790.
[12:29:58.480]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationJobService.ResolveJobPriorityClasses(IVssRequestContext requestContext, IEnumerable`1 jobReferences, ITFLogger logger)
[12:29:58.480]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationJobService.QueueJobsRaw(IVssRequestContext requestContext, IEnumerable`1 jobReferences, JobPriorityLevel priorityLevel, Int32 maxDelaySeconds, ITFLogger logger, Boolean queueAsDormant)
[12:29:58.480]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Deploy.TFCollection.GitStepPerformer.M83PopulateCommitChanges(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ServicingContext servicingContext)
[12:29:58.480]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.PerformHostStep(String servicingOperation, ServicingOperationTarget target, IServicingStep servicingStep, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
[12:29:58.480]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.PerformStep(String servicingOperation, ServicingOperationTarget target, String stepType, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
[12:29:58.480]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Int32 stepNumber, Int32 totalSteps)
[12:29:58.480] Step failed: Populate commit changes. Execution time: 23 milliseconds.
[12:29:58.480]   [StepDuration] 0.0236576
[12:29:58.480]   [GroupDuration] 0.2517195
[12:29:58.480]   [OperationDuration] 0.2517302
[12:29:58.587]   Clearing dictionary, removing all items.

======================================================================================================
 Step execution times in descending order
======================================================================================================
Updates all rows in tbl_GitCommit and sets the Status to ... (GitToDev14M83Collection, ToDev14M83Collection) - 227 milliseconds
Populate commit changes (GitToDev14M83Collection, ToDev14M83Collection)                                      - 23 milliseconds
Write service level to stamp (StartInstallUpdates, StartInstallUpdates)                                      - 20 milliseconds
Configure framework servicing tokens (VsspToDev14M71Collection, VsspToDev14M71Collection)                    - 20 milliseconds
Setup integration environment (TestManagementToDev12M65FinalConfiguration, ToDev12M65FinalConfiguration)     - 3 milliseconds
Setup Git environment (GitToDev14M74Collection, ToDev14M74Collection)                                        - 1 millisecond
Setup Git environment (GitToDev14M83Collection, ToDev14M83Collection)                                        - 1 millisecond
Set the collection partition id tokens in servicing context (GitToDev14M83Collection, ToDev14M83Collection)  - 1 millisecond

======================================================================================================
 Execution times by group in descending order
======================================================================================================
GitToDev14M83Collection (ToDev14M83Collection)                                                               - 250 milliseconds
StartInstallUpdates (StartInstallUpdates)                                                                    - 20 milliseconds
VsspToDev14M71Collection (VsspToDev14M71Collection)                                                          - 20 milliseconds
TestManagementToDev12M65FinalConfiguration (ToDev12M65FinalConfiguration)                                    - 3 milliseconds
GitToDev14M74Collection (ToDev14M74Collection)                                                               - 1 millisecond
```

I was pondering the fact that this is a rouge job that needs to be deleted from the databse manually but I mmight be wrong. Any pointer will be greatfully +1-ed.

Comment: Did you get any related log error info in event view?

Comment: This particular case is not getting any event viewer record generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, there was no way to recover the collection. So I used the admin command to permanently remove the collection. In my case, n one came back to me asking where the collection go so it's solved for me. I'm running the latest TFS 2017.2 and the rest of the dev are happy.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for TFS being unable to upgrade team project collections usually is that their data was already either **corrupted**, **incomplete**, or **stuck** between schema versions.

You will need to contact customer support for assistance troubleshooting these data issues and getting your data back to a workable state.

Since there is only one project inside. If you don't care the source control history and have the back up of project. A crude (not recommend) way should be deleting the special project collection, delete the database from SQL Server and create a new collection, restore the project inside.

Also take a look at this similar question with the same error as you: [Starting a team project collection after detaching and attaching again](https://serverfault.com/questions/669814/starting-a-team-project-collection-after-detaching-and-attaching-again)